# how to deal with the timeout when using require.ensure in webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

`webpack` place the `require.ensure` and `import` to load async chunk.

In webpack2, we can use `import` to load the async chunk. It returns a promise, so if it loads failed we can catch the err and do something.

```
import("./module").then(module => {
   return module.default;
}).catch(err => {
   console.log("Chunk loading failed");
});
```

If using the `require.ensure`. How can I deal with the timeout or something wrong when loading the async chunk failed?